# Replacing cell specific seperator in Google Sheets - 21.06.2019 to 21/06/2019

Tags: arrays, date, google-sheets, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

can someone help me in replacing periods with forwarding slashes in sheets?
I have a data set with over 100 thousand rows in sheets,
I have a date-time formatted as such D.M.Y  I need to change it to D/M/Y
each row has 7 or so columns based on date-time.
anyways, below is the first 6 rows of column 'A'
so its format is D.M.Y 
so I have 100,000 rows of this in column 'A'

`Date
21.06.2019 
22.06.2019 
23.06.2019
24.06.2019 
25.06.2019
26.06.2019`

I want to turn it into this

`Date
21/06/2019 
22/06/2019 
23/06/2019
24/06/2019 
25/06/2019
26/06/2019`

I need it in this format as sheet does not recognize the '.' as a separator and it would take an eternity to do it manually, thanks!
A link to my screen below to see the format

[image]

Comment: if you will change column A and the result in column A too, so I suggest you to use macro, you take the first row and the last row and then change each row in column A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check if your dates are valid dates with:

```
=ISDATE(A2)
```

if yes use this in B2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXT(A2:A; "dd/mm/yyyy"))
```

if no you can use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(A2:A; "."; "/"))
```

[image: 0]

---

and if you need real dates do:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(IFERROR(DATEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(A2:A; "."; "/"))); 
 "format(Col1) 'dd/mm/yyyy'"))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Worked perfect, Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is on Sheet1 in columns A through G.

On a blank tab, say Sheet2, in cell A1, you could use this formula to substitute the `.` with `/`.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(Sheet1!A:G,".","/"))
```

This should give you the substituted values. You could then copy these and paste them as *values* to Sheet1.

Comment: Hi thanks for reply, Im not sure what you mean by Sheet1!  ?
and all my dates are in column A

A, 0  = Date
A, 1  = 21.06.2019 
A, 2  = 22.06.2019 
A, 3  = 23.06.2019
A, 4  = 24.06.2019 
A, 5  = 25.06.2019
A, 6  = 26.06.2019

Comment: Do you want to share a dummy sample of your Sheet? May be easier to explain there.

Comment: I just added a picture to the original post, not sure if that will help? not sure how to share a dummy sample or what that is lol, super new to this :P

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use macro or script do like this:

```
function ReplaceDotToSlash()
 {
   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('YourSheetName');
   var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow(); 
   for (var i = 1; i < lastRow+1; i++){
     var value1 = sheet.getRange('A'+i).getValue() + "";
     sheet.getRange('A'+i).setValue(value1.replace(/\./g, "/"));
   }
 }
```